# Filter lines containing floating numbers that are larger than X.Y

Tags: filter, floating-point, sed, numbers, line

I am trying to make a very simple shell script that frees up some memory space. For this, I am using command

```
$ ps xopmem o%c
```

to output a list of running processes with its percentual memory usage. Now, I want to filter out only those lines whose value (in the first field) is larger than, say 5.0. How can I do that? I preferably use SED.

P.S.: I Googled around this topic on the Internet but found nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sed` cannot do numerical comparisons, you need to move one tool up, i.e. `awk`:

```
ps xopmem o%c | awk '$1 > 5.0'
```

That is, when the first field is greater than 5, execute the default block: `{ print $0 }`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am searching for.

Comment: +1, but the `{print}` is redundant.  It is sufficient to write `awk '$1 > 2.0'`

Comment: That's right `{ print }` is implicit if no code block is given, nice.

Answer (score 1):

One way. `-n` swith avoids printing automatically and the regexp matches any spaces at the beginning and any number bigger than 5.0. The `p` instruction prints lines that matches the previous regexp.

```
ps xopmem o%c | sed -ne '/^ *[5-9]\.[0-9]/ p'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but the value 5.0 is meant as a variable and is a way too complicated to change it in this code. Anyway, this code does not output anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps xopmem o%c | sort -nr | \
    while read line
    do v=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1); 
      [[ $v < 5 ]] && break; 
      echo $line; 
    done
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this did not worked for me and it's a way too long.